# GoogleMaps add tint

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to apply a tint to GoogleMaps surrounding two markers. So far the only working solution I got is to actually draw polygon on map as

```
map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                .addAll(createRectangle(SphericalUtil.interpolate(markerData.getStartPoint(), markerData.getEndPoint(), CENTER_POINT_INTERPOLATE), 90, 45))
                .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .fillColor(resources.getColor(R.color.tint_black_40)));
```

where `createRectangle()` is method from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/PolygonDemoActivity.java

```
private List<LatLng> createRectangle(LatLng center, double halfWidth, double halfHeight) {
    return Arrays.asList(new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth),
        new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude + halfWidth),
        new LatLng(center.latitude + halfHeight, center.longitude + halfWidth),
        new LatLng(center.latitude + halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth),
        new LatLng(center.latitude - halfHeight, center.longitude - halfWidth));
}
```

However created overlay doesn't cover whole map preview
[image: map preview]. Does anybody can help me out to improve existing approach or suggest better way how to tackle this?

Comment: So, do you need to cover the full map with a semi-transparent color?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `TileOverlay` and add it to the map (over or under your markers, depending on the zIndex).

The idea is to create a `TileProvider` that returns always a very small (2x2 pixels in my example) image that will be draw on the map. To ensure performance, the `Tile` returned by the `TileProvider` will always be the same.

Here is the code:

```
public class BackgroundTileProvider implements TileProvider {
    private Tile tile;

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        if (tile == null) {
            // Create a very small (for performance) bitmap with alpha
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            // Draw the desired color to use as background
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 0));

            // Get the bytes and create the Tile
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            tile = new Tile(2, 2, stream.toByteArray());
        }

        return tile;
    }
}
```

You will need to add the `TileOverlay` to your map as follows:

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new BackgroundTileProvider();
TileOverlay tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(
    new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

Comment: Thanks @antonio this did work to some extend. As per my previously attached screenshot right side of map is now tinted. However there is strip on left side that does not get coloured. It seems something to do with map rendering after `animateCamera`. Initial render of maps with tint is fine, only centering and zooming  is applied left side looses tinted tile. Nevertheless above helped me a lot. Thanx

Comment: That's odd. I can't reproduce your issue on my device. Can you share the relevant parts of your code? In particular I would like to test using your map initialization (move camera, and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

Writing down the essential code to create the polygon with tint effect.

```
private PolygonOptions mPolygonOptions;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPolygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    }
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mGoogleMap == null) {
            mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.locationtrackmap));
            mGoogleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
           mPolygonOptions.add(new LatLng(latitudeLongitude.One,latitudeLongitude.One));
           mPolygonOptions.add(new LatLng(latitudeLongitude.Two,latitudeLongitude.Two));
           mPolygonOptions.add(new LatLng(latitudeLongitude.Three,latitudeLongitude.Three));
           mPolygonOptions.add(new LatLng(latitudeLongitude.One,latitudeLongitude.One));
           mPolygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
           mPolygonOptions.strokeWidth(5);
           mPolygonOptions.fillColor(0x220000FF);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLon_to_focus, 14.0f));
                mGoogleMap.addPolygon(mPolygonOptions);}
    }
```